# JPanel rapidly toggling isDisplayable()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, rendering

Basically, I am writing a game based on Minesweeper, and am having a hard time getting the grid to render properly. The grid's class extends JPanel, and is properly added to the JFrame.

This is my rendering method:

```
public void buildTexture(){
    if(this.isDisplayable()){
        System.out.println("Can display panel");
        image = this.createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
        Tile[][] t = getCurrentSide();
        for(int a = 0; a < t.length; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < t.length; b++){
                if(t[a][b].visible){
                    Image i = t[a][b].getCurrentImage();
                    g.drawImage(i, 20*a, 20*b, this);
                }
            }
        }
        this.prepareImage(image, this);
        g.dispose();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Cannot display panel");
    }
}
```

`image` is an Image, declared as:

```
image = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

The above method is called by this thread, defined and started in the constructor.

```
Thread repainter = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (repaint) {
                buildTexture();
                repaint();
                try {
                    sleep(20);//50 ticks a second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    };
    repainter.start();
```

Basically, the issue is as follows: with this code, the output looks like this:

```
Cannot display panel
Can display panel
Can display panel
Cannot display panel
Cannot display panel
Can display panel
Cannot display panel
Can display panel
Can display panel
Cannot display panel
Cannot display panel
Can display panel
Can display panel
Cannot display panel
Can display panel
Cannot display panel
Can display panel
Cannot display panel
```

I have verified that `getCurrentSide()` and `getCurrentImage()` work as intended.
I have also verified that the `JFrame` this is on is visible, enabled, focusable, and valid.

EDIT: To clarify, I want it to only output "Can display panel"

EDIT: I replaced the Thread with a Timer. The toggling is now less random, it now toggles each iteration.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Instead of the thread loop you are using to do your refresh, you should use javax.swing.Timer

Comment: depending on your build hierarchy alot of stuff can go crazy - you want always to display "can display panel"? or strictly alternating? I cannot trust isDisplayable() -  maybe you can use something else

Comment: I am using isDisplayable() because, if the component is not displayable, this.createImage() will return null. So, I want it to always say "can display panel"

Comment: Just a thought, but you may be refreshing too quickly for Swing to handle. 50hz is pretty quick, try slowing it down and see if the toggling continues.

Comment: 25Hz had exactly the same output that 50Hz did.

Comment: Could it be because the Timer that I replaced the above thread with is calling repaint()?

Comment: Fixed it, it was a lot of stuff that I changed. Essentially, instead of a loop, I simply repainted every time it was needed. Also, I put the method call in paintComponent(), and used that graphics object. That seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Thread/Timer to call repaint() and buildTexture(), I put buildTexture() in paintComponent(Graphics), and used the graphics that is passed in to that method. That completely fixed the problem that I was having.